# Filtering get-adobject with Powershell

Tags: powershell, active-directory

Could some one tell me the issues with the query.

I want to pull back all the users that are not in a number of specific OU, I thought the following query would work, but as you can see it pulls back a user with "ou=staff" in the DN (extracted from all of the output).

I am trying to say if non of the following appear in the DN attribute.

```
$NotinDirectory = Get-ADObject  -LDAPFilter "objectClass=person" -SearchBase "OU=Accounts,DC=Company,DC=ac,DC=uk" -Properties ou |? {($_.DistinguishedName -notlike "*Agency*" -and "*Contractors*" -and "*Fellows*" -and "*Visitors*" -and "*ou=Staff*" -and "*Contacts*")}
```

CN=jo blogs,OU=Staff,OU=Accounts,DC=compnay,DC=ac,DC=uk

UPDATE
so I tried this based on comments bellow

```
 $NotinDirectory = Get-ADObject  -LDAPFilter "objectClass=person" -SearchBase "OU=Accounts,OU=iah,DC=iah,DC=ac,DC=uk"  | ? {($_DistinguishedName -notlike "*Agency*" -and $_DistinguishedName -notlike "*Contractors*" -and $_DistinguishedName -notlike "*Fellows*" ) -and ($_DistinguishedName -notlike"*Visitors*") -and ($_DistinguishedName -notlike"*OU=Staff*" -and $_DistinguishedName -notlike"*Contacts*")}
foreach ($test in $NotinDirectory){ Write-Host $test.DistinguishedName}
```

but i still get 
CN=xxx xxxxx,OU=Staff,OU=Accounts,DC=company,DC=ac,DC=uk

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `Where-Object` filter:

```
($_.DistinguishedName -notlike "*Agency*" -and "*Contractors*" -and "*Fellows*" -and "*Visitors*" -and "*ou=Staff*" -and "*Contacts*")
```

you only compare `$_.DistinguishedName` to a string *once*, the first time (`-notlike "*Agency*"`).

It will be parsed as follows:

```
(($_.DistinguishedName -notlike "*Agency*") -and ("*Contractors*") -and ("*Fellows*") -and ("*Visitors*") -and ("*ou=Staff*") -and ("*Contacts*"))
(($_.DistinguishedName -notlike "*Agency*") -and $true -and $true -and $true -and $true -and $true)
($_.DistinguishedName -notlike "*Agency*")
```

You'll have to do:

```
Get-ADObject | Where-Object {($_.DistinguishedName -notlike "*Agency*" -and 
    $_.DistinguishedName -notlike "*Contractors*" -and 
    $_.DistinguishedName -notlike "*Fellows*" -and 
    $_.DistinguishedName -notlike "*Visitors*" -and 
    $_.DistinguishedName -notlike "*ou=Staff*" -and 
    $_.DistinguishedName -notlike "*Contacts*")}
```

in order to test for all 6 strings.

---

If you have a variable number of strings you want to exclude, you can use `ForEach-Object` inside `Where-Object`:

```
$Excludes = "*Agency*","*Contractors*","*Fellows*","*Visitors*","*ou=Staff*","*Contacts*"

Get-ADObject |Where-Object {
    $ADObj = $_
    @($Excludes |ForEach-Object {
        $ADObj.DistinguishedName -notlike $_
    }) -notcontains $false
}
```

Comment: I tell you this might be one of the few I have not tried yet :)

Comment: Hi please see my edit, I had tried this before but getting the same result

Comment: Ignore me, next time I will put the "." in the $_.Dist....! I will also borrow that nice little loop. I was planning on some thing similar my self as I need to make this in to a function but that's a great start for me. Thank you for the help

Comment: You could also use `Where-Object` similar to your question by using `-match` and a regular expression like so `?{$_.DistinguishedName -match 'OU=(Accounts|Contractors|Fellows)'}`